Why is my fetch data not syncing in the correct order with nuxt 3 and pinia?
I'm trying to make a request for a login form using pinia in nuxt 3.
The fetch is done and the data is received, but not in the correct order and pinia is unable to store the user data received from the server. Always remaining as null.
My code looks like this:
\composables\useApiFetch.ts
import type {UseFetchOptions} from 'nuxt/app'
import {useRequestHeaders} from "nuxt/app";

export function useApiFetch<T>(path: string, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
  const apibaseurl = runtimeConfig.public.apiBaseUrl;

  let headers: any = {}

  const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
 
  if (token.value) {
    headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = token.value as string;
  }

  const result = ref<any | null>(null);
  const error = ref<Error | null>(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await useFetch(apibaseurl + path, {
        watch: false,
        ...options,
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          ...options?.headers
        }
      });

      // The data in this line is called after the pinia has already been completed.
      console.log("DATA VAL "+JSON.stringify(data.value));
      
      result.value = data.value;
    } catch (err) {
      error.value = err as Error;
    }
  };

  fetchData();

  return { result, error };
}

\stores\useAuthStore.ts
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { useApiFetch } from "~/composables/useApiFetch";

type User = {
  authtoken: string;
  sid: string;
  uid: number;
  nickname: string;
  picture: string;
  name: string;
  given_name: string;
  email: string;
  activated: boolean;
  admin: boolean;
};

type Credentials = {
  userlogin: string;
  password: string;
  remember: boolean;
};

type RegistrationInfo = {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  password_confirmation: string;
};

type LogoutToken = {
  token: string;
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
  state: () => ({
    user: null as User | null,
  }),

  actions: {
    async fetchUser() {
      const { result, error } = await useApiFetch("/auth/check");
      this.user = result.value as User;
    },

    async login(credentials: Credentials) {
      const login = await useApiFetch("/auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        body: credentials,
      });

      // This line is executed before receiving data from the fetch and the data is null
      console.log("LOGIN PINIA:"+JSON.stringify(login.result));

      this.user = login.result.value;
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(this.user));

      return login;
    },

    async register(info: RegistrationInfo) {
      const register = await useApiFetch<User>("/auth/register", {
        method: "POST",
        body: info,
      });

      return register;
    },

    async logout() {
      await useApiFetch<User>("/auth/logout", { method: "POST" });
      this.user = null;
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
    },

    isLoggedIn(): boolean {
      return !!this.user;
    },
  },

  getters: {
    getUser(state): User | null {
      return state.user;
    },
  },
});

And I call it in my form like this:
\page\login.vue
<script setup>
    import {useAuthStore} from "~/stores/useAuthStore";
    
    definePageMeta({
      layout: 'default'
    })

    const form = ref({
      userlogin: "",
      password: "",
      remember: false
    });

    const auth = useAuthStore();

    async function handleLogin() {
      const loginresult = await auth.login(form.value);
    }
</script>

what am I doing wrong? How can I fix it so that the login receives the fetch data and stores it correctly without being null?
